# Uniform convergence counter-examples

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

1. If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of real functions on the interval $[0, 1]$ converging uniformly to a function $f$ on $[0, 1]$, and if each $f_n$ is continuous except at countably many points, does it follow that there exists a point at which $f$ is continuous?
2. If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of differentiable functions on $[0, 1]$ converging uniformly to a function $f$ on $[0, 1]$, does it follow that there exists a point at which $f$ is differentiable?

I'm trying to see if I can prove or give counter-examples to the above. I can't see a way to prove them, so I am looking for counter-examples.

Comment: For 2, just pick your favorite continuos and nowhere differentiable function and approximate it uniformly by polynomials; for 1, note that $f_n$ are all continuos (together) except at countable many points as the union of discontinuity points is countable

Comment: Could you elaborate on 1? How does that relate to the limit? For 2, is there an easier function to choose than the Weierstrass function?

Comment: Not sure what is the question - if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on an interval and $f_n$ continuos at a point $x_0$ in that interval for all $n$, then $f$ is continuos at $x_0$; as noted, the union of discontinuity points for $f_n$ is countable, so there are uncountably many points where all $f_n$ hence $f$ is continuos

Comment: Very clearly a counter-example to 2 will require a continuous no-where differentiable function. Polynomials are dense under the uniform topology in $C([0,1])$ (or any other compact set), so it would seem hard to get any easier than that.